# How to print output in stand alone capybara

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

I have standalone capybara script to do acceptance testing on my live application. I want to printout the results on console after completing the test cases, for some reason nothing is printed on my terminal even though my test cases are pass.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/webkit'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  config.default_driver = :webkit 
  config.javascript_driver = :webkit
  config.app_host = 'https://dx.com/' # change url
  config.timeout = 40
end


Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
 config.allow_unknown_urls
end

module DxBat
  class Test

  include RSpec::Matchers
    include Capybara::DSL
    def login
      visit("/")
        fill_in "emailAddress", :with => "sd_auto_bat@dx.com"
        fill_in "password", :with => "123456"
    click_button("submit")
    page.should have_content 'Dashboard'
  end
  end
end

t = DxBat::Test.new
t.login
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Loganathans-MacBook-Pro:Desktop Logan$ ruby sd_bat.rb 
Loganathans-MacBook-Pro:Desktop Logan$
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I want to know whether text got failed or succecceded, like we have o/p in rspec

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you're not actually running a test through any sort of test runner here.  All you've done is define a class, create an instance and then call a method on that instance.  If you want output that says "Passed" just add a `puts` after calling `t.login`

```
...
t.login
puts "Passed!"
```

if the `should` in your login method fails it will raise an exception and the `puts` will never be executed, if it passes then login will just return and the `puts` will be exectued.

Comment: Thanks, I will add rspec runner